# how to convert date to date drop down and drop down could be separate day, month,year

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

[image: i need this type of dropdown[![][2]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zovgm.png)

```html
<p>
  <label for="id_date_of_birth">Date of birth:</label>
  <input type="date" name="date_of_birth" value="2019-06-14" id="id_date_of_birth">
</p>
```

> i am getting data from database by using django and i am trying to show in drop down date but i am getting date table

Comment: convert `<input type="text">` to `<select></select>`

Comment: previous it's in text only i converted to date      $('#id_date_of_birth').get(0).type = 'date';

Comment: Ages ago I created [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/109765/javascript-date-validation) post on CodeReviews, but this will help you. Do refer

Comment: @BTR Can you please provide a screenshot how it should look like so that it would be easy to provide solution.

Comment: i added can you check there

Answer (score 1):

In your Django form, set the widget for your `DateField` to the `SelectDateWidget` (import it from `django.forms.widgets`). Then you only need to do `{{ form.date_of_birth }}` in your template.

```
class ProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    form_class = MyProfileForm

class MyProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        widgets = {'date_of_birth': SelectDateWidget()}
```

Comment: yaa i am using already SelectDateWidget in my forms but here i am getting data from database and i am using UpdateView

Comment: So? Then I don’t understand the problem. Using the UpdateView doesn’t prevent you from using your forms with the SelectDateWidget

Comment: **SelectDateWidget** is only suitable for date should get data from end user to database and it displaying drop down nice but the thing is here i am using **Update View** for updating already existed data in database. In my html i am using **{{form.as_p}}** if i use **{{form.date_of_birth}}** its same like 16/10/2019 but i need here also drop down like SelectDateWidget

Answer (score 0):

You can split out the field into 3 parts (you'd need to get the day/month/year parts in django) into 3 select fields like this:

```
<p>
  <label>Day:
    <select name="day">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      ...
      <option>31</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label>Month:
    <select name="month">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      ...
      <option>12</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label>Year:
    <select name="year">
      <option>1900</option>
      <option>1901</option>
      ...
      <option>3000</option>
    </select>
  </label>
```

But I would **NOT** recommend this. This makes entering dates harder (multiple clicks and scrolls), the user can't copy/paste dates, or choose from a visual calendar.  You also need to add your own client side logic to ensure that the user doesn't pick dates like Feb 31st.

Comment: yaa it's too hard and my  client requirement is date month year drop down form separately

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

If you are.. not a good idea <3

```html
<select name='day'>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
  <option value='4'>4</option>
  <option value='5'>5</option>
  <option value='6'>6</option>
  <option value='7'>7</option>
  <option value='8'>8</option>
  <option value='9'>9</option>
  <option value='10'>10</option>
  <option value='11'>11</option>
  <option value='12'>12</option>
  <option value='13'>13</option>
  <option value='14'>14</option>
  <option value='15'>15</option>
  <option value='16'>16</option>
  <option value='17'>17</option>
  <option value='18'>18</option>
  <option value='19'>19</option>
  <option value='20'>20</option>
  <option value='21'>21</option>
  <option value='22'>22</option>
  <option value='23'>23</option>
  <option value='24'>24</option>
  <option value='25'>25</option>
  <option value='26'>26</option>
  <option value='27'>27</option>
  <option value='28'>28</option>
  <option value='29'>29</option>
  <option value='30'>30</option>
  <option value='31'>31</option>
</select>

<select name='month'>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
  <option value='4'>4</option>
  <option value='5'>5</option>
  <option value='6'>6</option>
  <option value='7'>7</option>
  <option value='8'>8</option>
  <option value='9'>9</option>
  <option value='10'>10</option>
  <option value='11'>11</option>
  <option value='12'>12</option>
</select>

<select name='day'>
  <option value='2019'>2019</option>
  <option value='2018'>2018</option>
  <option value='2017'>2017</option>
  <option value='2016'>2016</option>
  <option value='2015'>2015</option>
  <option value='2014'>2014</option>
  <option value='2013'>2013</option>
  <option value='2012'>2012</option>
  <option value='2011'>2011</option>
  <option value='2010'>2010</option>
  <option value='2009'>2009</option>
  <option value='2008'>2008</option>
  <option value='2007'>2007</option>
  <option value='2006'>2006</option>
  <option value='2005'>2005</option>
  <option value='2004'>2004</option>
  <option value='2003'>2003</option>
  <option value='2002'>2002</option>
  <option value='2001'>2001</option>
  <option value='2000'>2000</option>
  <option value='1999'>1999</option>
  <option value='1998'>1998</option>
  <option value='1997'>1997</option>
  <option value='1996'>1996</option>
  <option value='1995'>1995</option>
  <option value='1994'>1994</option>
  <option value='1993'>1993</option>
  <option value='1992'>1992</option>
  <option value='1991'>1991</option>
  <option value='1990'>1990</option>
</select>
```

Comment: yaa yaa i need like this but instead of month number i need name

Comment: Then just change the html so months instead of numbers and it works :)

Comment: that's fine how to split day,month and year of my value and how to insert separate day,month and year to particular select tag that's problem

Comment: They are already splitted, just change "1" to "january" and so on :)